# Number of solutions of the equation $z^\alpha=1$ where $\alpha$ is real.

Tags: complex-analysis

I was just studying complex analysis by myself, and I got stuck with this problem. The problem is essentially just asking about the number of solutions of $z^\alpha=1$ where $\alpha$ is real and $z$ is complex.

If $\alpha$ is an integer, all possible $z$'s are given as the nth root of unity, so there are $n$ of them.

If $\alpha$ is rational, then I can write $\alpha=\frac{q}{p}$, and take the power of $p$ in each side, so we get $z^{q}=1$. Not all of $q$-roots of unity satisfy the original solution, so we would need to delete some of them.

If $\alpha$ is irrational, suppose $\alpha=\pi$, then how would I know the number of the solutions of $z^\pi=1$?

This might be a really dumb question, and I'm new to complex analysis, so help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we define $z^\alpha=\exp(\alpha\ln z)$ and choose the principal branch of $\arg$ to lie in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$, then the number of solutions is equal to the number of integers in $(-\frac{\alpha}{2},\frac{\alpha}{2}]$ for $\alpha>0$ or $[\frac{\alpha}{2},-\frac{\alpha}{2})$ for $\alpha>0$. The number of solutions is $1$ for $\alpha\in(-2,0)\cup(0,2)$, $3$ for $\alpha\in(-4,-2)\cup(2,4)$, $5$ for $\alpha\in(-6,-4)\cup(4,6)$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of solutions is actually infinity. It is actually trivial, when $\alpha$ is 0.

For the $z^\pi=1$ answer, look here: [How many solutions has $z^\pi = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98805/how-many-solutions-has-z-pi-1)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Couldn't find it by myself. Changing the problem in polar forms, i.e. $$z=re^{i\theta} \quad z^pi=r^\pi e^{i\pi\theta}=1$$ and this implies that $r^\pi=1$ and $\theta=2n$ for integer $n$. Since we can't find a natural number $m$ such that $2n\times m=2l\pi$, so there are infinite number of solutions. Thanks, that got clear. Just one more question, would the set of solutions be dense in the set $\{z | |z|=1\}$?