# Number of roots of a function

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

If $z^3= 2$, one has 3 roots.

If $z^4= 2$, one has 4 roots.

What about $z^\pi = 2$ ? How many roots it has? And what is the procedure to find them?

Comment: Well, it must have $\pi$ roots, of course

Comment: are you familiar with De Moivre's theorem?

Comment: See:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882910/complex-number-raised-to-irrational-power and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98805/how-many-solutions-has-z-pi-1

Answer (score 3):

Serious answer, assuming you are familiar with Euler's identity, etc, let
$$z=re^{i\theta}\implies z^\pi=r^\pi e^{\pi i\theta},$$
Therefore $r=2^{\frac{1}{\pi}},$ and $\pi\theta=2\pi k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$; hence
$$\theta=2k.$$
Or in cartesian coordinates,
$$z=2^\frac{1}{\pi}(\cos(2k)+i\sin(2k)).$$
Due to these angles being irrational multiples of $\pi$, they are *countably infinite* in number.

---

**Small addendum:** It's usually stated that the exponent tells us how many roots a complex number has, but if we want to be more technical, it's something of a measure of the rotational symmetry of the roots. There are infinite roots for all complex numbers, but for integer (and rational) exponents, these roots perfectly overlap, producing only finitely many distinct roots.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i was thinking. To your comment, I add the fact we can approximate an irrational number as a fraction. So, for a precision estipulated, one can take a finite number of roots

Comment: @Graviton What other solutions are there besides $\exp\left(\frac{\ln(2)}\pi+2ki\right),k=-1,0,1$? When $k=2$, it is [not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5Eπ%2Cz%3Dexp%28%28ln%282.0%29%2B4πi%29%2Fπ%29) a solution

Comment: @TymaGaidash All integer values for $k$ theoretically work, but most calculators like WolframAlpha assume only the principal branch of the logarithm. Try typing [$(e^{4i})^\pi$ into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28e%5E%284i%29%29%5Epi) for example.